# using future_lapply() inside future_lapply()

Tags: r, lapply, r-future

I am iterating over a function that uses `future_lapply()`. I want to parallelize the *outside* lapply, for which I would use the following code:

```
plan(multisession, workers = 10)
future_lapply(X = 1:10, FUN = myfun)
```

Now, `myfun()` has its own `future_lapply()` inside. How do I configure the plan inside `myfun()` so that it does not mess up with the *outside* plan?

Inside `myFun()`, I am using

```
o.plan <- plan()
plan(sequential) 
on.exit(plan(o.plan), add = TRUE)
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Could you add an argument to ```myfun(..., in_parallel = FALSE)``` and then change between ```future_lapply()``` and ```lapply()``` based on that arg?

Comment: @Cole yes, that is what I thought, but I was hoping for a better solution, without having to repeat code...

Comment: I'm curious about what a good solution to this is as well. In the meantime, you could do something like ```my_lapply = if (in_parallel) lapply else future_lapply``` and then just use ```my_lapply(...)```

Comment: @Cole future_lapply has additional arguments like `future_seed`, this also complicates the call.

Comment: It may work to have a plan inside a plan, something like:

```plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = 2)), tweak(multisession, workers = 8)))```

Beware of overloading things.